# OpenLDAP TLS failing with TLS init def ctx failed: -69

Tags: openssl, openldap

I have been trying for 2 days to get OpenLDAP to work with TLS where I have a site certificate signed by my own Intermediate CA which was signed by my own Root CA. And no matter what I've tried I get the **TLS init def ctx failed: -69** in syslog and slapd doesn't start.

I've run ldapmodify on the following an received an exit code of 0:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ca-certs/ca-ica.cert.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/site.cert.crt
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile:
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/sasl2/site.key.crt
```

I've set the owner of these files to openldap. I've chmod 640 on site.key.crt.
ca-ica.cert.crt was created by cat intermediate.crt ca.cert > ca-ica.cert.crt

I know the certificate chain verifies because I run `openssl verify -CAfile ca-ica.cert.crt site.cert.crt` and it works fine.

I even tried using `olcTLSCertificatePath` on a c_rehash directory. Nothing works.

If I just try a simple self-signed certificate things work fine and I can connect with StartTLS.

I am about 20% knowledgeable on OpenLDAP and about 30% knowledgeable on certificate management. But I'm flummoxed.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated**
I ran slapd with -d trace. Here's the syslog output.
Thanks for helping. `/usr/sbin/slapd --version` returns ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21. The certs are PEM format generated with openssl version 1.01f from 6 Jan 2014. Yea. It's old.
syslog contents with -d trace.

```
May 18 15:45:22 JohnLaptop kernel: [1017829.972053] type=1400 audit(1589834722.159:158): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/slapd" name="/home/john/openldap-certs/ca.crt" pid=21376 comm="slapd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=119 ouid=119
```

I was messing around with it and am now getting a -1 instead of a -69.

Comment: Please try to run slapd in debug mode to get more information, for example: `slapd -u openldap -g openldap -d trace`. I assume this is the distro-provided OpenLDAP package on a Debian/Ubuntu/derivative distro? What version exactly? Error -69 is GNUTLS_E_ASN1_DER_ERROR; I guess your certificates are in DER format? If so, have you tried converting to PEM instead?

Comment: Thanks for helping. `/usr/sbin/slapd --version` returns ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21. The certs are PEM format generated with openssl version 1.01f from 6 Jan 2014. Yea. It's old.

Comment: The debug output gets printed directly to stderr, it doesn't go to syslog. I'm not sure how `ls (GNU coreutils)` made it into the version output, but please try `dpkg-query -W slapd` if you installed with apt-get, or `/usr/sbin/slapd -VV` otherwise.

Comment: openldap was running on a very old version of ubuntu. I upgraded to LTS 20 and reinstalled openldap to bring everything up to date. I've now got things working securely. I'm pretty certain the old gnuTLS conflicts were an issue. I found a good run through for TLS and openldap here: https://kifarunix.com/setup-openldap-server-with-ssl-tls-on-debian-10/#ldap-ssl-tls

Answer (score 1):

I assume based on the paths and error code that the TLS library in use is GnuTLS.

From https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Error-codes.html, error -69 is `GNUTLS_E_ASN1_DER_ERROR`.

From searching Google, it seems that this can be emitted if the certificate is considered invalid, and that GnuTLS can be more strict than OpenSSL on some points. A recent example is: https://gitlab.com/gnutls/gnutls/-/issues/196

You might get more useful feedback if you try to validate the chain using GnuTLS' certtool (`apt install gnutls-bin`). https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/certtool-Invocation.html

Comment: I tried generating the certificate with certtool as well. Getting 
`main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1`

Comment: I only suggested running your existing cert through certtool to try and find out why GnuTLS didn't like it. I didn't mean you needed to generate a whole new one!

Comment: OpenLDAP uses OpenSSL.

Comment: On your system, maybe. The distro-provided OpenLDAP packages on Debian and Ubuntu use GnuTLS. Based on the presence of `/etc/ldap` and AppArmor in this case, I'm guessing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

From your update:

```
May 18 15:45:22 JohnLaptop kernel: [1017829.972053] type=1400 audit(1589834722.159:158): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/slapd" name="/home/john/openldap-certs/ca.crt" pid=21376 comm="slapd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=119 ouid=119
```

That's an AppArmor denial.

The profile at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd` contains the files and folders slapd has access to. `/home/john/openldap-certs/ca.crt` is not among them; if you want to use that location, you'll have to disable the profile (o ju, or add your path to it.

If you just want to temporarily shut up AppArmor for debugging, you can set it to complain mode:

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/slapd
```

When you're done and want to enable it again:

```
sudo aa-enforce /usr/sbin/slapd
```

More info about AppArmor on the Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor